# Support libraries don't work with aar

Tags: android, maven, android-support-library

I'm facing a problem in my library project. I have added in `build.gradle` of the lib the support dependencies and I have used them in my code. When I build the `.aar` file to use on `Maven`, the support dependencies are "ignored", they aren't seen by the project in which I use the lib.

Here is the warning I receive in the `gradle` of the lib:

`Dependency on a support library, but the SDK installation does not have the "Extras > Android Support Repository" installed. Open the SDK manager and install it.`

Obviously i have the last version of the support repositories installed.

[image]

Here is the gradle of the lib:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
 }
}
```

In my project in which I add the lib as dependency, for example in styles.xml, I can't see AppCompat themes.

And here is the gradle of the app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "giorgioantonioli.fondesa.spesapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile ('com.fondesa:antoniolimaterial:1.0.0@aar'){ //lib
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @HugoGresse Now i can't try it, but when i'll do, i'll write the response

Comment: @HugoGresse that didn't solve the issue

Comment: I've tried you're code and it's working as it should. Be sure to have updated SDK (I know you say you have but...) https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcz6rxfjgxf3l14/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-06-16%2011.33.12.png?dl=0

Comment: I've also tested in a library and it's working

Comment: @HugoGresse see edits

Comment: did you try a `Build> Clean Project`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80652/discussion-between-fondesa-and-hugo-gresse).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80657/discussion-between-fondesa-and-hugo-gresse).

Comment: How do you import the lib in your project as dependency?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti check the edit of the question

Comment: Do you get it from a local maven?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes he is

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes, actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I didn't added the dependencies to my .pom file of the lib:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.fondesa</groupId>
  <artifactId>antoniolimaterial</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <name>Antonioli Material</name>
  <description>Antonioli material library</description>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>giorgio.antonioli</id>
      <name>Giorgio Antonioli</name>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
      <version>22.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
      <version>22.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>recyclerview-v7</artifactId>
      <version>22.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>design</artifactId>
      <version>22.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And after i added it in maven local with:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=pathtoaar\antoniolimaterial-release.aar 
-DgroupId=com.fondesa 
-DartifactId=antoniolimaterial -Dversion=1.0.0 
-Dpackaging=aar 
-DpomFile=pathtopom\antoniolimaterial.pom
```